# Exposing a column in an Oracle SQL CASE statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to modify an SQL select statement to select the inverse value of a column (as in, negative if the value was positive, positive if the value was negative) based on the value of a different column.

This (not inversed) works:

```
BSEG_WBTR as INVOICE_AMOUNT
```

But this does not:

```
CASE
  WHEN BSEG_SHKZG = 'S' THEN
    -BSEG_WBTR
  ELSE
    BSEG_WBTR
  END AS INVOICE_AMOUNT,
```

Giving the error of:

> [Error] Execution (13: 45): ORA-00904: "BSEG_WBTR": invalid identifier

Which seems to imply that BSEG_WBTR is no longer exposed once inside the CASE statement.

How do I expose a column to be used inside of a CASE statement?

Comment: Are you sure that's where the error points to? What you wrote should work, it is not true that the column goes out of scope in a CASE statement. Is that the exact portion of the query? (I ask because the error starts at column 45, I don't see anything 45 characters long in what you wrote). Which line, specifically, is line 13 in your code?

Comment: @Allan Your new SQL did do the trick and works. If you'd like to recreate the answer I'd happily accept it.

Comment: Is BSEG_WBTR an alias?  If so, it will not be available in the select statment.  If not, and it is available on the table you are selecting from, there is nothing special you have to do to expose it in within the case statement.

Comment: It was actually incorrect. Some trial and error has revealed that your initial code in the question _should_ work. I think that @mathguy was on the right track that the `case` is a red herring.

Comment: @mathguy The actual query is nearly 200 lines long and involves multiple joins, and lots of indentation. I removed the indentation for the most part to make it more readable.

Comment: @Allan Hm. I'm not sure then. When I copied your SQL in it worked, and it's what I'm going to go with.

Comment: @NexTerren - that is why I asked. Can you tell, by looking at your own code, exactly which line the error points to? Is it the third line of the code you posted (with the minus sign), or the fifth line (the ELSE branch)? Or neither?

Answer (score 1):

Just multiply the value by -1.  Try this:

```
CASE
  WHEN BSEG_SHKZG = 'S' THEN
    BSEG_WBTR * -1
  ELSE
    BSEG_WBTR
  END AS INVOICE_AMOUNT,
```

Comment: But WHY?  -BSEG_WBTR should be the same value, why would * -1 work where the unary operator fails?

Comment: You are correct.  They should both work.  I misunderstood the question - it appears that he has some sort of error that is being caused by unposted code.

Answer (score 0):

The query below shows three methods of accomplishing what you are attempting. My preferred syntax is the second (use the column name once, with the `case` providing a multiplier).

```
SELECT CASE WHEN bseg_shkzg = 'S' THEN -bseg_wbtr ELSE bseg_wbtr END
          AS invoice_amount,
       bseg_wbtr * CASE bseg_shkzg WHEN 'S' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END
          AS invoice_amount2,
       CASE WHEN bseg_shkzg = 'S' THEN 0 - bseg_wbtr ELSE bseg_wbtr END
          AS invoice_amount3
FROM   (SELECT 10 AS bseg_wbtr, 'S' AS bseg_shkzg FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 20 AS bseg_wbtr, 'R' AS bseg_shkzg FROM DUAL)
```

The first appears to be what you initially tried, so I'm not sure that the error you're seeing is directly related to the error you're getting.

Comment: Updating the SQL with this change does not remove or change the error message.

Comment: Then obviously the error must be elsewhere in your code, since what Allan posted works. (Just copy it and paste it in your SQL interface and run it - this proves the error is NOT where you think it is.)

Answer (score 0):

> To select the inverse value of a column (as in, negative if the value was positive, positive if the value was negative) based on the value of a different column.

Multiply any value with `-1` will return the inverse value.

Example:

```
DECLARE @BSEG_SHKZG AS INT = 2;
SELECT @BSEG_SHKZG * -1  -- results -2

DECLARE @BSEG_SHKZG_ AS INT = -2;
SELECT @BSEG_SHKZG_ * -1  -- results 2
```

So the below query will return your expected result:

```
CASE
WHEN BSEG_SHKZG = 'S' THEN
    BSEG_WBTR * -1
ELSE
    BSEG_WBTR
END AS INVOICE_AMOUNT
```

Comment: But WHY?  -BSEG_WBTR should be the same value, why would * -1 work where the unary operator fails?